# Trouble with navigating between tabsheets in code

Tags: delphi-7

I am having a problem with navigating between tab sheets in code.

1. I have a button that will be clicked
2. In the OnClick event the next tabsheet should become the active tabsheet

I am looking for the code to put in the button that will make the active tabsheet move from the current tabsheet to the next tabsheet. I am using a page control with two pages.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as it stands your question is unintelligible

Answer (score 1):

[`TPageControl`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TPageControl) has a [`SelectNextPage()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TPageControl.SelectNextPage) method for this very purpose, eg:

```
PageControl1.SelectNextPage(True);
```